# inherit css style from component and use it in another

Tags: css

I've got special styles for the object like this

```
form#sign_in{
    position:relative;
    margin:85px auto 50px auto;
    width:455px;
    background:#fff;
    border:#dfdfdf 1px solid;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
}
```

I want to apply all `sign_in` style to another component except width

```
form#another_sign_in{
    width: 520px;
}
```

How to inherit it from `form#sign_in`?

Comment: use classes you can reuse them

Comment: [here](https://pascalprecht.github.io/2014/08/01/sharing-styles-across-web-components-with-polymer-and-core-style/) you can find an article about `core-styles` in polymer;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should make a default class for your login forms (or select them by form tag if you want to apply the style to every form). Then also make extra ids or classes for specifying the width for every form.

```
.default_sign_in{
    position:relative;
    margin:85px auto 50px auto;
    background:#fff;
    border:#dfdfdf 1px solid;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
}

.big_form{
     width:700px;
}
.small_form{
     width:350px;
}
```

html

```
<form class="default_sign_in big_form">...</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

As said, make a class with those common styles. Or without creating extra class:

```
form#sign_in, form#another_sign_in{
    position:relative;
    margin:85px auto 50px auto;
    background:#fff;
    border:#dfdfdf 1px solid;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
}

form#sign_in{
    width:455px;
}

form#another_sign_in{
    width: 520px;
}
```

---

I'd suggest that you look at some CSS preprocessor, like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) where you can create a [mixin](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#mixins):

```
@mixin formStyles($width){
    width:$width;
    position:relative;
    margin:85px auto 50px auto;
    background:#fff;
    border:#dfdfdf 1px solid;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;   
}
```

And use it like:

```
form#sign_in{
    @include formStyles(455px);
}

form#another_sign_in{
    @include formStyles(520px);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding two id's for same element is not possible here.

You can add the same class attribute for the two form elements and then additional add one more class to the second form.

**HTML:**

```
<form class="sign_in">.....</form>
<form class="sign_in another_sign_in">....</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
form.sign_in{
    position:relative;
    margin:85px auto 50px auto;
    width:455px;
    background:#fff;
    border:#dfdfdf 1px solid;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
}

form.another_sign_in{
width: 520px;
}
```